# Run All Validations Except Any of "kind" :presence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

Is there a way to run only validations of a specific type?

I have an application that updates multiple class instances in a single form.  Validations are performed by creating an instance of *building* and validating on that.

The problem: if an attribute isn't being updated, the form field is left blank and the form submits an empty string.  You can see an example here where params[:building][:name] is an empty string.

params = {:building=>{:name=>"", :short_name=>"", :code=>"test"}, :commit=>"Update Buildings", :building_ids=>["2", "5", "7"], :action=>"update_multiple", :controller=>"buildings"}

How can I run all the validations excluding those that check for the presence of an attribute?

```
def update_multiple
  @building = Building.new(params[:building].reject {|k,v| v.blank?})

  respond_to do |format|
    if @building.valid?
      Building.update_all( params[:building].reject {|k,v| v.blank?}, {:id => params[:building_ids]} )
      format.html { redirect_to buildings_path, notice: 'Buildings successfully updated.' }
    else
      @buildings = Building.all
      format.html { render action: 'edit_multiple' }
    end
  end
end
```

I've spent quite a bit of time working on this, and here's what I've found so far:

To retrieve a models validations

```
$ Building.validators
=> [#<ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x007fbdf4d6f0b0 @attributes=[:name], @options={}>]
```

To get a validators *kind*

```
$ Building.validators[0].kind
=> :presence
```

This is the method used by rails to run validations:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb
line 353

```
  # This method runs callback chain for the given kind.
  # If this called first time it creates a new callback method for the kind.
  # This generated method plays caching role.
  #
  def __run_callbacks(kind, object, &blk) #:nodoc:
    name = __callback_runner_name(kind)
    unless object.respond_to?(name, true)
      str = object.send("_#{kind}_callbacks").compile
      class_eval <<-RUBY_EVAL, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
        def #{name}() #{str} end
        protected :#{name}
      RUBY_EVAL
    end
    object.send(name, &blk)
  end
```

If there is a way to run validations directly?  If so, I could iterate over the `Building.validators` and only run those with `kind != :presence`.

I'd love to hear any ideas you have.

Answer (score 0):

I think circumventing specific validations is an interesting idea, but I think there's an easier way. I'd handle this by writing a custom method that validates batch updates, something like this:

```
def valid_for_batch?(params)
  @building = Building.new(params[:building].reject {|k,v| v.blank?})
  @building.name = "Foo" if @building.name.blank?
  @building.shortname = "Bar" if @building.shortname.blank?
  # etc...
  @building.valid?
end
```

Just make sure that "Foo" and "Bar" up there are values that will pass your validation - all that code is doing is looking to see if the values are empty and if so, replacing them with a temporary value that will pass validation. That way, the only way that `@building.valid?` will return false at the end is if there were existing bad data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, it looks like a hack like this is necessary.  It makes for messy code though, especially if you want to allow "bulk edits" for multiple models.

Using your idea, I created a more generalized solution which I'll post.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, after working on this issue for many hours, it looks to be a very difficult problem.

Create a class instance `@building` and set placeholders for attributes whose presence is validated.

I've tried many different approaches and this is the best I can come up with so far.

```
def update_multiple
  valid = true

  @building = Building.new(params[:building])
  set_bulk_edit_placeholders_for_presence_validators(@building)
  building_valid = @building.valid?

  # Check if buildings were selected to edit
  if params[:building_ids].blank?
    valid = false
    @building.errors.add(:base, 'You must select at least one Building')
  end

  # Check if all form fields are blank
  if params[:building].values.delete_if {|v| v.blank?}.blank?
    valid = false
    @building.errors.add(:base, 'The edit form must not be empty')
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if valid && building_valid
      @buildings = Building.find(params[:building_ids])
      @buildings.each do |building|
        building.update_attributes!(params[:building].reject { |k,v| v.blank? })
      end
      format.html { redirect_to buildings_path, notice: 'Buildings were successfully updated.' }
    else
      @buildings = Building.all
      format.html { render edit_multiple_buildings_path }
    end
  end
end
```

This is a general function to set the placeholders.  It can be used for any model from any controller.

application_controller.rb

```
private

def set_bulk_edit_placeholders_for_presence_validators(class_instance, hash={})
  model_name = hash[:model_name] || self.class.name.sub("Controller", "").singularize.downcase
  klass = self.class.name.sub("Controller", "").singularize.constantize
  klass.send(:validators).each { |validator|
    if (validator.kind == :presence)
      validator.attributes.each { |attribute|
        if params[model_name][attribute].blank?
          class_instance.send("#{attribute}=", 'placeholder')
        end
      }
    end
  }
end
```

In order to display the errors properly on the form it has to be a `form_for @buildings`.
Since the placeholders are set for the @buildings object, we have to specify that the form values come directly from `params`.

edit_multiple.haml

```
= bootstrap_form_for @building, :url => update_multiple_buildings_path, :method => :put, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f|
  = f.text_field :name, :value => params[:building].try(:send, :[], :name)
  = f.text_field :short_name, :value => params[:building].try(:send, :[], :short_name)
  = f.text_field :code, :value => params[:building].try(:send, :[], :code)

  = f.submit 'Update Buildings', :name => nil

  %table.table.table-striped.table-bordered
    %thead
      %tr
        %th.check_box_column= check_box_tag 'select_all'
        %th.sortable= sortable :name
        %th Abbr Name
        %th.sortable= sortable :code
        %th
    %tbody
      - @buildings.each do |building|
        %tr
          %td.check_box_column= check_box_tag 'building_ids[]', building.id, (params[:building_ids].include?(building.id.to_s) if params[:building_ids])
          %td= building.name
          %td= building.short_name
          %td= building.code
          %td.links.span2
            = link_to 'Show', building
            = link_to 'Edit', edit_building_path(building)
            = link_to 'Delete', building, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this building?'
```

I hope this can be of help to others working on similar "bulk update" validation issues.